# Shouldnt testing IPN take money from my Paypal sandbox account?

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Im trying to set up a PayPal IPN system on my site, but I try to test it in the PayPal sandbox, I think it's not working fine.

I've got a developer account in the sandbox. I've created 2 accounts: buyer and seller. I use the IPN simulator to send a POST request to my page. The request seems just fine, but when I login into the sandbox seller account, the amount of money didnt change. If I login with the buyer account, the amount didnt change either. Shouldnt they change according with the IPN purchase I just simulate?

Also, if I go to IPN record in the paypal account, it's empty.

If I send back the request to PayPal to verify it, I get: VERIFIED from PayPal, so it seems correct.

I post here the POST request Im getting from PayPal:

```
cmd=_notify-validate
test_ipn=1
payment_type=instant
payment_date=10%3A21%3A42+Apr+03%2C+2011+PDT
payment_status=Completed
address_status=confirmed
payer_status=verified
first_name=John
last_name=Smith
payer_email=buyer_1301850921_per%40my_email.net
payer_id=TESTBUYERID01
address_name=John+Smith
address_country=United+States
address_country_code=US
address_zip=95131
address_state=CA
address_city=San+Jose
address_street=123%2C+any+street
business=seller_1301846568_biz%40my_email.net
receiver_email=seller_1301846568_biz%40my_email.net
receiver_id=M3PZFZDNE3HKU
residence_country=US
item_name=something
item_number=AK-1234
quantity=1
shipping=3.04
tax=2.02
mc_currency=EUR
mc_fee=0
mc_gross=15
mc_gross_1=10
txn_type=web_accept
txn_id=42431721
notify_version=2.1
custom=Los+23+pinos
charset=windows-1252
verify_sign=AGJ1AjjJzH2s7fC2Gg3c.JDtZCK1A.hF6JlaXSYSYzM-krKKk.SLx50l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that IPN does NOT simulate the transfer of funds, so if you want to test it you need to point your checkout form to the sandbox URL

Answer (score 0):

IPN is not a transactional functionality. It merely allows PayPal to send you a POST with transaction data whenever a transaction has been made.

If you're looking to transfer funds, you'd be looking at either Website Payments Standard, Express Checkout, Website Payments Pro, Paflow Link, Payflow Pro or Adaptive Payments.

Comment: I meant transfer funds of the sandbox accounts, not the real ones. Anyway, I found out that IPN does NOT simulate the transfer of funds, so if you want to test it you need to point your checkout form to the sandbox URL.

Comment: That's correct. That's what I said in my first sentence as well :-)